# Why the mysql MSI Installer is more huge than wamp installer packages size?

Tags: mysql, wamp

In http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html, you can get Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer  whose size is 252.6M .
In http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/, you can get wampserver installer packages whose size is only  39.8M.
I am confused that wampserver contain apache\mysql\php ,why 1+1+1<1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Installer provides an easy to use, wizard-based installation experience for all your MySQL software needs. Included in the product are the latest versions of:

```
MySQL Server
MySQL Connectors
MySQL Workbench and sample models
Sample Databases
MySQL for Excel
MySQL Notifier
MySQL for Visual Studio
Documentation
```

While WAMP comes only with MySQL-Server (no client tools etc), not 100% sure but did you see if the wamp-setup is offline installer only?

Comment: The wamp-setup is onlline installer .

Comment: So that's your answer of why :)